# iOS:Help Blur screen on the top of home view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

my application needs help sceen on top of the home view controller.I have taken the tabbar controller as a root view controller and added navigation view controller .So in  appearance of the first screen both tabbar and navigation bar appears along with view body.When i tried to place the help screens by pageviewcontroller  examples at the time of view did load in the first screen tab view and navigation bar are coming front keeping the page view controller back .i have tried

```
   [self addChildViewController:walkthrough];
   [self.view addSubview:walkthrough.view];
   [self.tabBarController.view bringSubviewToFront:walkthrough.view];
```

please help how to get the page view screen front.And is there any examples tutorial please help me 
Note:Botn navigation bar and tabbar should not be hide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I have done for walkthrough in my application. You can download this FXBlurView library from here: 
https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXBlurView

In my .h file

```
#import "FXBlurView.h"
IBOutlet UIView *viewWalkThrough;
FXBlurView *overlayView;
```

In my .m file

```
#define SYSTEM_SCREEN_SIZE [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size
#define kProfileWalkthrough  @"ProfileWalkthrough"

if (![[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:kProfileWalkthrough] boolValue]) {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:kProfileWalkthrough];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    overlayView = [[FXBlurView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, SYSTEM_SCREEN_SIZE.width, SYSTEM_SCREEN_SIZE.height)];
    [overlayView setDynamic:YES];
    [overlayView setBlurRadius:5.0f];
    [overlayView setBlurEnabled:YES];
    [overlayView setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [self.view.window addSubview:overlayView];
    [self displayOverlay:viewWalkThrough aboveView:self.view.window];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(closeWalkThrough:)];
    [viewWalkThrough addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
}

- (void)closeWalkThrough:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapRecognizer {
[overlayView          removeFromSuperview];
[self.viewWalkThrough removeFromSuperview];
```

}

```
- (void)displayOverlay:(UIView *)subView aboveView:(UIView *)superView {
subView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

[superView addSubview:subView];
[superView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[subView]|" options:kNilOptions metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(subView)]];
[superView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[subView]|" options:kNilOptions metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(subView)]];

[superView layoutSubviews];
```

}

Comment: i had nearly 6 screen that would ack like page view controller not like single ui that is also above the tabbar and navigation bar

Comment: You can add view of that pageview controller as a subview to window rather than your home view controller.